# Pyhton mover arquivos conforme a quantidade

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar um script que:

- Mova de uma pasta origem para uma pasta destino 9 arquivos que comecem com `'_A_'`.

obs: Dentro da pasta origem haverão dezenas de arquivos começando com `'_A_'`, mas desejo que sejam movidos apenas 9.

**Código**

```
import shutil
import os

pasta_origem = r'D:\Pasta_Origem'    # pasta de origem
pasta_destino = r'D:\Pasta_Destino'  # pasta de destino
files = os.listdir(pasta_origem)     # lista os arquivos dentro da pasta
os.chdir(pasta_origem)               # vai para o diretorio de destino

# este loop é para selecionar apenas 9 arquivos que comecem com '_A_'.
# dentro desta pasta haverao dezenas de arquivos comecando com '_A_', quero que ele pegue so 9.

for file in files:
   if file.startswith('_A_') and files.count(9):
       print(file)  # apenas para visualizar os arquivos que serao movidos
       shutil.move(file, pasta_destino)
```

Answer (score 3):

`files.count(9)` conta quantas vezes o int `9` aparece na lista `files`. Como ele não aparece nehuma vez (`files` é uma lista de strings), retorna `0`. Uma condicional na forma

```
if alguma_expressao and 0
```

sempre será falsa, uma vez que `bool(0)` equivale a `False`. Logo, as linhas abaixo da condicional como você escreveu nunca são executadas.

Use um contador simples para executar algo N vezes, por exemplo:

```
files_to_move = 9
for file in files:
    if file.startswith('_A_'):
        print(file)  # apenas para visualizar os arquivos que serao movidos
        shutil.move(file, pasta_destino)
        files_to_move -= 1
    if files_to_move == 0:  # sair do loop
        break
```

Comment: Cara, perfeito!!!!
era exatamente o que queria.
antes de realizar a pergunta, estava há mais de 1 semana tentando fazer.
muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar :)